# How do you sort a dictionary by key from highest to lowest

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have a dictionary that is currently the one below:

```
dictionary={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
```

my desired output is to have a dictionary with the highest keys to the left and the lowest keys to the right like below:

```
dictionary={3:'c',2:'b',1:'a'}
```

how do you do that in python 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), reverse=True))
```

This is duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: Thanks, yes it is but I wasn't sure how to reverse the order. So sorta different

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the keys from the dictionary with `dictionary.keys()`, then sort it in reverse with `sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True)`, and then you can use that in a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: dictionary[k] for k in sorted(dictionary.keys(), reverse=True)}
# {3: 'c', 2: 'b', 1: 'a'}
```

Of course, if we use `sorted` on a `dict` it will return the sorted keys anyway, so we can simplify this slightly to:

```
{k: dictionary[k] for k in sorted(dictionary, reverse=True)}
# {3: 'c', 2: 'b', 1: 'a'}
```

This does seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though. You may want to consider why it matters what order the keys are in? How does that affect your program?